# I don't know how to use Tweepy; can you tell me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I install Tweepy and Python-Twitter and try code, and I tried to run.

If I try this code:

```
import tweepy
import time
#insert your Twitter keys here
consumer_key ='xxx'
consumer_secret='xxx'
access_token='xxx'
access_token_secret='xxx'
twitter_handle='handle'

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

list= open('twitter_followers.txt','w')

if(api.verify_credentials):
    print ('We successfully logged in')

user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_handle).items()

while True:
    try:
        u = next(user)
        list.write(u.screen_name +' \n')

    except:
        time.sleep(15*60)
        print ('We got a timeout ... Sleeping for 15 minutes')
        u = next(user)
        list.write(u.screen_name +' \n')
list.close()
```

I get this error when I do:

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx.py", line 19, in <module>
    user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_handle).items()
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'followers'
```

Are there any errors that have not been progressed yet?

Comment: It looks like the example code you copied from is incorrect, the method name is actually `api.get_followers`.

Comment: Also, a bare `except` is bad practice in almost all cases as it hides things like `StopIteration` exceptions and `KeyboardInterupt`, instead you want to use `except tweepy.RateLimitError`

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) renamed `API.followers` to [`API.get_followers`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.get_followers).

Also, you're not calling [`API.verify_credentials`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.verify_credentials) and instead only checking if the method exists, so that `if` statement expression will always evaluate to `True` and `print`.